# Unable to install package synthetic-minion

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, newrelic

Unable to install newrelic cpm, after performing below steps in screenshot it cant locate the image I downloaded from quay.io

Am I giving the command wrong or path is wrong?

[image: error]

[image: error2]

Answer (score 2):

CPM chart location has changed, you may be still referring the old repo. Update your repo according to the notice [here](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/synthetics-minion-helm-chart-url-update/188119) and reinstall.

Comment: Yes it appeared to be related to helm chart version, but after running the helm repo update command the issue is as below. helm install cpm-ap-south-1 cpm/synthetics-minion -n newrelic --set synthetics.privateLocationKey=**
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

Comment: Initially, your chart location is outdated, this is not related to helm version. The invalid apiVersion is a separate issue. Open your .kube/config and update "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" to "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1" will do.

Comment: Can you provide the commands pls

Comment: Thanks got it working after updating CLI version and .kube/config