# While trying to install Kubernetes based CPM, facing issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, newrelic

I am trying to install Kubernetes based Containerized Private Minion(CPM) using helm and I am getting below error. Also I have updated the helm repo as well. Need help.

[image: error]

Answer (score 3):

The invalid apiVersion is a separate issue. Open your .kube/config and update "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" to "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1" will do.

Origin question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73219633/unable-to-install-package-synthetic-minion).

Comment: Can you share the commands pls

Comment: First of all your aws cli **must** be version 2.7.7 and above, recommended helm version v3.9 and above. Start with `kubectl config view --minify`, take note of the user name. If you are on Windows, open the `C:\Users\<name>\.kube\config` or Linux `~/.kube/config` with your favorite editor, look for the user and update the `apiVersion` to `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1` under the `exec` section.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, the CLI version mismatch was the issue.